# How can you interpret "できるもんなら作るよ ってのが"

Tags: meaning, modality

I am able to understand できるもんなら作る, but I don't understand the way ってのが is used, which I've come to learn is the contraction of というのが

So, in which way is ってのが being used?

Answer (score 2):

っての is というの, and が is a plain subject marker. So it's basically like this:

> "I'd make it if it were something I can make" **is ...**

This is an incomplete sentence, and the corresponding predicate is missing. Maybe you've missed the remaining part of this sentence in the following page, or maybe the predicate of this sentence can be inferred from the context. If this still doesn't make sense, please share the context (perhaps several sentences before and after this).

Comment: This is what whats missing 後は勝手に注文してくれれば, this is before the sentence that I asked about

Comment: @Oscar The context is still lacking. I cannot even tell what is the object of this 作る.

Comment: I believe the context is from the tv show [深夜食堂 (Midnight diner)](https://moji-village.hatenadiary.com/entry/midnight-dinner)I actually came across this question by searching for もんなら on this site whilst watching the show. The main character is a chef who says he will cook whatever you like, as long as he has the ingredients （マスター） 食べたいもの言ってくれりゃ できるもんなら作るよ.